# Override document.location.replace with document.location.assign in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, tampermonkey

I am asking this for personal user. I have full admin access and can write a chrome extension or do anything else required. I don't like this and prefer to see all history items. Is it possible to override it locally for myself.

Comment: IIRC `location` object is not replaceable as per the specification so you can't override it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible to listen to this event and cancel it?

Comment: You can use browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to cancel the navigation, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm I know about it. But I don't think I can check if it was caused by location.replace or something else there?

Comment: I *think* an extension, but not Tampermonkey, can still do this.  But if it can't, an extension should be able to keep a shadow history (in the extension's storage) to fill in the gaps.